# Resharper ignores [DeploymentItem] if no build occurs

Tags: unit-testing, deployment, resharper, mstest

I have a unit test written in MSTest with a deployment item decorator to copy a configuration file.

The test itself deletes a line from the configuration file and then verifies the delete occurred correctly.

Now here is the rub.

If I run the test again in ReSharper, it refuses to redeploy the item again, instead leaving the previous copy of the file there, now already missing a line, and the test fails.

If I run the same test again, but using MStest, it passes.

It appears MSTest will always honor [DeploymentItem] even when a build does not occur, but ReSharper will only deploy items if an actual build takes place.

Anyone else seen this?

Using Visual Studio 2012 and ReSharper 7.1.3